# jQuery selector input select first and second

Tags: jquery

Right now I have two selects on my page:

```
<div id="exportSelection">
    <select name="ddlRubrique" id="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
    </select>

    <select name="_ddlSubRubrique" id="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I've been using this jQuery:

```
jQuery("#_ddlSubRubrique").chained("#ddlRubrique");
```

but to make is more reliable i would like to tell the selector to select first select and select second select in this div `#exportSelection`.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("selector:eq(0),selector:eq(1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`.eq()`**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and pass the 0-based index of the element:

```
var $selects = $('#exportSelection select');
// first: $selects.eq(0)
// second: $selects.eq(1)
```